# Adding the results of different counts on the same query

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this (it has more columns, obviously, but I'm simplifying):

table:

```
|region|-status-|
|------|--------|
|north |status1 |
|north |status1 |
|north |status1 |
|north |status2 |
|north |status3 |
|south |status1 |
|south |status2 |
|south |status2 |
|south |status3 |
|east  |status1 |
|east  |status2 |
|east  |status2 |
|east  |status4 |
|west  |status4 |
```

The query I have is something like this:

```
SELECT region,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN region='north' THEN 1 END) as status1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN region='south' THEN 1 END) as status2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN region='east' THEN 1 END) as status3,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN region='west' THEN 1 END) as status4
FROM table
GROUP BY region;
```

Which gives me this table:

```
|region|status1|status2|status3|status4|
|north |      3|      1|      1|      0|
|south |      1|      2|      1|      0|
|east  |      1|      2|      0|      1|
|west  |      0|      0|      0|      2|
```

And what I need, is to add a column so I can get columns where I addd a sum of diferent fields, like this:

```
|region|status1|status2|status3|status4|(status1+status2)|(status 3+status4)|
|north |      3|      1|      1|      0|                4|                 1|
|south |      1|      2|      1|      0|                3|                 1|
|east  |      1|      2|      0|      1|                3|                 1|
|west  |      0|      0|      0|      2|                0|                 2|
```

Any ideas how I could do it? I'm way too rusty to be solving this, and it's a work thing, so any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: ```CASE WHEN region IN ('north', 'south') THEN 1 END) AS `status1+status2` ```

Comment: Are you sure that the result of your query looks like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match multiple values with `IN`.

```
SELECT region,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN region='north' THEN 1 END) as status1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN region='south' THEN 1 END) as status2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN region='east' THEN 1 END) as status3,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN region='west' THEN 1 END) as status4,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN region IN ('north', 'south') THEN 1 END) AS `status1+status2`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN region IN ('east', 'west') THEN 1 END) AS `status3+status4`,
FROM table
GROUP BY region;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are mismatches between your sample table data and the result you're getting. For example, `west` only have 1 row of data for `status4` in the sample table but your result is showing 2 counts. Also `COUNT(CASE ...` will give you total count even if the result is 1, 0 or NULL. That's just counting rows and you're not really telling the query *"if this is false, don't count it"* or *"if this is not 1, don't count it"*.

Your current query according to the sample data you've provided actually will return result as following:

| region | status1 | status2 | status3 | status4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| north | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| south | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| east | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| west | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Which is not similar to the results your getting in your post above. The correct query to achieve your result should be something like this:

```
SELECT region,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='status1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as status1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='status2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as status2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='status3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as status3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='status4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as status4
FROM mytable
GROUP BY region;
```

That will give you this results:

| region | status1 | status2 | status3 | status4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| north | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| south | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| east | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| west | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Alternatively, you can write the query much shorter like this:

```
SELECT region, 
       SUM(status='status1') AS status1,
       SUM(status='status2') AS status2,
       SUM(status='status3') AS status3,
       SUM(status='status4') AS status4
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY region;
```

Then, the last part of the query that you're looking for:

```
SELECT region,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='status1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as status1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='status2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as status2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='status3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as status3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='status4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as status4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ('status1','status2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'status1+status2',
    SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ('status3','status4') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'status3+status4'
FROM mytable
GROUP BY region;
```

OR the alternative:

```
SELECT region, 
       SUM(status='status1') AS status1,
       SUM(status='status2') AS status2,
       SUM(status='status3') AS status3,
       SUM(status='status4') AS status4,
       SUM(status IN ('status1','status2')) AS 'status1+status2',
       SUM(status IN ('status3','status4')) AS 'status3+status4'
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY region;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54546044623e3020906d3e69eabde559)